# Selenium Web Driver- Element is not located when tried with Xpath.Could anyone suggest better way to locate below element?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

`Selenium Web Driver`- Element is not located when tried with `Xpath`. Could anyone suggest better way to locate below element?

```
<div class="gwt-Label">Declined</div>
```

I tried below to get text in that element

```
findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[12]/div")).getText();
```

Comment: depends o the site you are checking, but you don't have to give all the path for getting the xpath node, you can use `//` to get directly to the one you want, check [the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these `XPath`es:

```
findElement(By.xpath('//div[@class="gwt-Label"]')).getText();
findElement(By.xpath('//div[text()="Declined"]')).getText();
```

or `cssSelector`:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("div.gwt-Label")).getText();
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I tried below which workedfindElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Declined']")).getText();

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add property (for example) `data-e2e="my_element"` to your `div` and call it by:

```
myTarget: {
  selector: '[data-e2e="my_element"]'
}
```

Comment: "Simply"? :) Apply `JavaScript` to set new attribute to use it then as element locator... Yeah, looks quite obvious :))